# ReactJS axios post: returns null when it comes/goes from/to backend

Tags: reactjs, post, http-headers, rest

I am stuck on this problem for 2 days. I am sending `POST`request from [frontend](https://github.com/rd9911/UniHelsinkiFullStack/tree/main/part2/part2-2) to the [backend](https://github.com/rd9911/UniHelsinkiFullStack/tree/main/part3) (and other `GET` requests too but the problem is only with `POST`). However, when my data goes to the backend it does not post anything to the rest api even though response is `200 OK`. That's why when in response it should have given the posted data, it can't find it and gives `null`. This is my `POST` code in backend [index.js](https://github.com/rd9911/UniHelsinkiFullStack/blob/main/part3/index.js):

```
const { response, request } = require('express');
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const Contact = require('./models/contact.cjs');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('build'))
app.use(cors())
morgan.token('body', req => {
    return JSON.stringify(req.body)
  })
app.use(morgan(':method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms :body'));

const generateId = () => {
    const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000)
    return randNum;
}

app.post('/api/persons', (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body
    console.log(body)
    if (!body.name || !body.number) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: "missing data"
        })
    } else if (Contact.find({name: body.name})) {
        Contact.findOneAndUpdate({name: body.name}, {$set: {number: body.number}}, {new:true})
            .then(updatedContacts => 
                res.json(updatedContacts)
            )
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
    } else {
        const contact = Contact({
            id: generateId(),
            name: body.name,
            number: body.number,
            date: new Date()
        })
        contact.save()
            .then(savedContact => {
                console.log(savedContact)
                res.json(savedContact)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    
    }
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is working on ${PORT}`)
})
```

and this is how my frontend sends data to backend: [contacts.js](https://github.com/rd9911/UniHelsinkiFullStack/blob/main/part2/part2-2/src/services/contacts.js):

```
const create = (newObject) => {
    const readyToPost = {
        method: 'post',
        url: `${baseUrl}`,
        data: newObject,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        json: true
      }
    const request = axios(readyToPost)
    return request.then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        return response.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

And [this](https://github.com/rd9911/UniHelsinkiFullStack/blob/main/part2/part2-2/src/App.js) is my react app's  frontend.

Any ideas about why my data becomes `null`?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Due to the **synchronous** nature of your code, the condition `Contact.find({name: body.name})` was always returning the `Query` object which is **true** due to which the `else if` block was getting executed even when there was no such document. After entering the `else if` block, since there was no match, so `findOneAndUpdate()` was returning **null**.
- Use `findOne()` instead of `find()`. `find()` returns a **cursor which is empty but true** whereas `findOne()` returns the **first document matched** (if matched) or else it will return **null** (if not matched).

```
// index.js (Backend)

app.post("/api/persons", async (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    if (!body.name || !body.number) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "missing data",
      });
    }

    // Using findOne() instead of find(). Returns null if record not found.
    const existing = await Contact.findOne({ name: body.name });
    if (existing) {
      Contact.findOneAndUpdate(
        { name: body.name },
        { $set: { number: body.number } },
        { new: true }
      )
        .then((updatedContacts) => {
          console.log(updatedContacts);
          res.status(200).json(updatedContacts);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    } else {
      const contact = Contact({
        id: generateId(),
        name: body.name,
        number: body.number,
        date: new Date(),
      });
      contact
        .save()
        .then((savedContact) => {
          console.log(savedContact);
          res.status(201).json(savedContact);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  });
```